# ADLA/U-SQL Error: Vertex user code error

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I just have a simple U-SQL that extracts a csv using  `Extractors.Csv(encoding:Encoding.[Unicode]);` and outputs into a lake store table. The file size is small around 600MB and is unicode type. The number of rows is 700K+

These are the columns:

```
UserId int,
Email string,
AltEmail string,
CreatedOn DateTime,
IsDeleted bool,
UserGuid Guid,
IFulfillmentContact bool,
IsBillingContact bool,
LastUpdateDate DateTime,
IsTermsOfUse string,
UserTypeId string
```

When I submit this job to my local, it works great without any issues. Once I submit it to ADLA, I get the following error:

```
Vertex failure triggered quick job abort. Vertex failed: SV1_Extract_Partition[0][0] with error: Vertex user code error.
Vertex failed with a fail-fast error
Vertex SV1_Extract_Partition[0][0].v1 {BA7B2378-597C-4679-AD69-07413A143E47} failed 

Error:
Vertex user code error

exitcode=CsExitCode_StillActive Errorsnippet=An error occurred while processing adl://lakestore.azuredatalakestore.net/Data/User.csv
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file is larger than 250MB, you need to make sure that you upload it as a row-oriented file and not a binary file.

Also, please check the reply for the following question to see how you currently can find more details on the error: [Debugging u-sql Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246517/debugging-u-sql-jobs/36269678#36269678)