# Where can I see error details for Azure Data Lake Analytics U-SQL jobs in case of failure?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

One way is to download file and run a local job to get error details. Sometimes it is hard to go this way. Is there any place where I can see error details, as the details shown at the portal or in job error panel are not complete and you can't reach to the cause of failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, how to you look at the error messages?

If you are using the Azure Portal, there is a fix planned to show all the error messages.

If you use VisualStudio, then please make sure you install the latest version of the ADL Tools for VS. Also, if you have access to the job profile, you can follow the steps outlined here if you feel you cannot see it all: [Debugging u-sql Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246517/debugging-u-sql-jobs/36269678#36269678) (although with the latest version of the ADL Tools for VS you should not need to have to look for it anymore).